# Error: `export_graph()` REASON: * The graph object is not valid

Tags: r, pdf, xgboost

I want to export graph to pdf in R, with the model of xgboost.
Unfortunately, I get the error in the title.

I followed the official advice to solve it, but it didn't work.

Anybody know about this? Do I need to do anything else?

This is what I did:

'Below is an example of how to save this plot to a file. 
Note that for `export_graph` to work, the DiagrammeRsvg and rsvg packages must also be installed.'

```
library(DiagrammeR)
gr <- xgb.plot.tree(model=bst, trees=0:1, render=FALSE)
export_graph(gr, 'tree.pdf', width=1500, height=1900)
export_graph(gr, 'tree.png', width=1500, height=1900)
```